# Numpy.array (500x50), How do I Concatenate across rows so that it becomes a (500x1)

Tags: python, numpy

Seems like it is a pretty simple problem to an experienced Python User

Struggling to manipulate my numpy.array, it currently is a 500x50 array of 10bit binary numbers, I would like to join all the numbers together across the rows to essentially create a 500x1 array

Any Advice 
Thanks

***Code***

```
Weight_Binary = np.array(Weight_int)
Weight_Binary=(np.array([np.binary_repr(a).zfill(10) 
     for b in Weight_Binary for a in b]).reshape(Weight_Binary.shape))

print(Weight_Binary.shape)
print(Weight_Binary)


(500, 50)
[['0110100010' '1011010010' '0000000000' ... '0100100101' '0100100000'
'0010000010']
['0000010011' '1010101000' '0011010100' ... '1000111110' '0000000010'
'1001101011']
['0101001000' '1000010000' '1101110111' ... '1011001001' '1000110000'
'0000001100']
```

I am looking to join these numbers across rows to give a 500x1 array. Or to create a new column at the end which is the result of concatenating these numbers together in which I can then utilise.

For example a singular example would be

```
 Weight_Binary[0,0]+Weight_Binary[0,1]

 Output '01101000101011010010'
```

But for the entire Array

Comment: Could you post an small sample of the input and the intended output?

Comment: Code Added in OP

Comment: So you want to joined to form a 500 length string for each column?

Comment: Exactly but struggling !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) along columns to concatenate the binary representations:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
weight_binary = np.random.randint(1000, size=(500, 50))
weight_binary = (np.array([np.binary_repr(a).zfill(10) for b in weight_binary for a in b]).reshape(weight_binary.shape))

result = np.array([''.join(column) for column in weight_binary])
print(result.shape)
print(result[0])
```

**Output**

```
(500,)
00011001100110110011110101110001000011100001101010000100011110101111000000010100100110011000011110010111010010001101011001010010100111001010000101011101011101000001100011110110011110100101110010000010101001010101001101001100000001010101011101111010110110011101110010010101100000010010111111111011101101000101000010100000011100101101001110010000010101001111110010111010111101011000100011000001110110100000111010011111111010101010010111011011101011101111110011111100001110001011110111101111011010101110
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to concatenate them on either axis, using [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
import numpy as np

shape_source = (4, 3)
shape_target = (4, 1)

np.random.seed(42)
array = np.random.randint(9, size=shape_source)

print(array)
# [[6 3 7]
#  [4 6 2]
#  [6 7 4]
#  [3 7 7]]

print(np.concatenate(array[:], axis=0))
# [6 3 7 4 6 2 6 7 4 3 7 7]

print(np.concatenate(np.matrix.transpose(array)[:], axis=0))
# [6 4 6 3 3 6 7 7 7 2 4 7]
```